# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' While fetching Json from jsonplaceholder.typecode.com/photos

Tags: json, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I am trying to fetch the JSON from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/ but getting error like Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I am still a learning flutter.

Any fixes?

Here is my code.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
import 'src/widgets/image_list.dart';
import 'src/models/imageloader.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "app",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: homePage(),
    );
  }
}

class homePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _homePageState createState() => _homePageState();
}

class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<ImageLoader> images = [];
  void loadImage() async {
    counter++;
    var response =
        await get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/'));
    var imageModel = ImageLoader.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    /*  var imagemodel = imageModel.map((i) => ImageLoader.fromJson(i)).toList(); */
    setState(() {
      images.add(imageModel);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Let's load some images"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: loadImage,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ImageList(images),
    );
  }
}
```

imageLoager.dart

```
class ImageLoader {
  int id = 0;
  String url = "";
  String title = "";

  ImageLoader(this.id, this.url, this.title);

  ImageLoader.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    id = parsedJson['id'];
    url = parsedJson['url'];
    title = parsedJson['title'];
  }
}
```

image_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/imageloader.dart';

class ImageList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ImageLoader> images;
  ImageList(
    this.images,
  );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: images.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return Text(images[index].url);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Debug Console:

Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 4984): #0      _homePageState.loadImage
package:imageloader/main.dart:33
E/flutter ( 4984): 
E/flutter ( 4984):

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're response comes in a list, which contains the maps that you want.
Use this under your `var response` line and it should work:

```
List<ImageLoader> _images = [];
var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

for (var item in decodedResponse) {
_images.add(ImageLoader.fromJson(item));
}

setState(() {
      images= _images;
    });
```